# Is it possible to have more than one ip src/dst address in a packet?

Tags: ip

I'm developing a CNN model to detect certain attacks on the network and while processing the data I got an error due to the existence of packets with 2 ip src/dst addresses concatenated with a comma. (2 src addresses and 2 dst addresses)
I handled the error but I want to know how there are packets with multiple ips. Is it because those packets are labeled as ARP spoofing attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IPv4 header contains the source and destination address, which are both in an 32bit field, so there is no space for any additional address (compare the header below):[image: IPv4 header]

Therefor a packet with two addresses cannot be processed and is dropped.

ARP spoofing is when a device with a different MAC address impersonates the original one. But the ARP response is send in two different packages and cannot be combined.